# Stop Event forwarding from children elements to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

let's suppose to have following code:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
    <div class="wall">
        <button>New</button>
        <div class="prova">
            <a href="localhost">ciao !</a>
        </div>
       <div class="prova">
            <a href="localhost">miao !</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the following js/jquery code:

```
function onBoot()
{
    $(".prova").draggable();

    $(".wall").mousedown(onMouseDown);
    $(".wall").mouseup(onMouseUp);
}


function onMouseDown(e)
{
    console.log("down");
}

function onMouseUp(e)
{
    console.log("up");
}


$(onBoot);
```

Now, I correctly see the button and the two divs.
When I click on "wall" (parent div) I see "down"/"up" on console as I expect.
However, I see "down"/"up" on console also when I click on "prova" divs and button too.
I know about "bubbling up" concept for which an event is forwarded from children to parent elements and I want to prevent it but without specifying an explicit event handler on "prova" divs.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the originators className, like this:

```
function onMouseDown(e)
{
  e = e || event;
  if ((e.srcElement || e.target).className === 'wall') {console.log("down");}
  return true;
}
```

see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/H99XE/)

Comment: Both solutions are good! Thanks guys. I give the correct answer to KooiInc because he provided an example on jsfiddle that clarified me a lot the stuffs. Howaver personally I like more the answer of Linus because it is more compact.

Answer (score 2):

In your event handler (`OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseUp`), check if `e.currentTarget` equals `e.target`. See [jQuery Events documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

> It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.

So, for example:

```
function onMouseDown(e)
{
    if(e.currentTarget !== e.target)
        return;

    console.log("down");
}
```

Comment: Note: `event.currentTarget` isn't supported in IE<9.

Comment: It isn't? I thought jQuery handled that?